# Bash has colors, bold and underlined characters. Why not Italic?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, fonts, zsh

I am naming bash, but the question applies to other linux shells as well.
Is there a reason why italic characters have not been included?

Comment: Answer: Not a function of `bash` or any other shell, but rather a function of the terminal device. If the terminal can do it, then (almost) any shell configured to send the commands.

Comment: I guess they didn't think it was needed. And I agree. I've never missed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `bash`. Most terminal applications simply don't support italic text.

[`pangoterm`](http://leonerds-code.blogspot.com/2011/09/libvtermpangoterm-and-tickit.html) is a notable exception:

[image: pangoterm showing off a number of features, including italics]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check some terminal definition supports italics (`stim`):

```
$ for ti in $(find /lib/terminfo /usr/share/terminfo -type f -print); do  t=${ti##*/}; if tput -T ${t} stim 2>/dev/null; then echo ${t} "supports italics"; fi; done
```